# How to change order of custom post types. I want Featured post to come first

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

Used this but not working:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'businesslistings',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => get_query_var('orderby'), // will return orderby query string variable
        'order' => '$var', 
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "featured posts" you mean sticky post, those posts *should* come first. You have to jump through hoops to prevent that. There is likely a filter in your theme or a plugin that is altering that default behavior. Search the `/wp-content/` directory for `pre_get_posts`.

If "sticky posts" is not what you mean, you are missing necessary query arguments but I can't tell which ones as you don't explain what constitutes a "featured post".

Secondly, your query arguments are wrong. `'order' => '$var',` instructs the query to order by the string literal `$var`, which will not work. [Variables do not expand inside single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Use double quotes, or, my preference, no quotes at all. You don't need them.